# Linked list setting up reference

Tags: java

Can someone explain why 
temp.setNext(current.getNext()); has been used I am not understanding

```
public void add(Object data, int index)
        // post: inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
        {
                Node temp = new Node(data);
                Node current = head;
                // crawl to the requested index or the last element in the list,
                // whichever comes first
                for(int i = 1; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++)
                {
                        current = current.getNext();
                }
                // set the new node's next-node reference to this node's next-node reference
                temp.setNext(current.getNext());
                // now set this node's next-node reference to the new node
                current.setNext(temp);
                listCount++;// increment the number of elements variable
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the new Node (referenced by the `temp` variable) to be inserted before the node at the `index` position, which is referenced by `current.getNext()` after the while loop is done.

Therefore you first set the next Node of `temp` to `current.getNext()` (`temp.setNext(current.getNext());`) and then set the next Node of `current` to `temp` (`current.setNext(temp);`). This places `temp` between `current` and the original `current.getNext()`.

before :

```
... -> current -> current.getNext() -> ...
```

after :

```
... -> current -> temp -> current.getNext() (the original current.getNext()) -> ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !! But what do you mean by original current.getnext()